# Project is not compatible with monoandroid81(MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was just coding in my Xamarin.Forms project, and suddenly, this error appeared:

`Project is not compatible with monoandroid81(MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Project TaskX.iOS supports: xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)`
I don´t really know what this means. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: this might help https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28314/you-are-trying-to-install-this-package-into-a-project-that-targets-xamarin-ios10

Answer (score 3):

After a few days of messing around, it worked when I installed the latest version -

I had 8.1 installed but as soon as I installed "Android SDK Platform 28" (Latest) + updated all sdk's everything worked

[image]

maybe updating the sdk's was the solution but just make sure you specify a installed (updated) android version correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another failing of the Visual Studio error list. I am getting this error on my Android projects and a very similar one on my IOS project. Neither project uses NHibernate. I can unload my NHibernate project and both my Android and IOS project still build. Yet the error remains. I can change the error list filter to Build so I can ignore this IntelliSense error. It's not much of a solution but neither is Visual Studio's error list.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue removing an android reference on my iOS project.

Expand reference on your iOS project and look for and .Droid and remove it